# Can one word be classified as two different word classes?

Tags: parts-of-speech, german, adjectives, participles

Over at German Language Stack Exchange, the question was asked what the structure of the sentence

> Ihr Antrag ist **abgelehnt.**

is, and what the word *abgelehnt* can be classified as. Traditional German grammar apparantly classifies the expression as a static passive (*Zustandspassiv*) in which the word *abgelehnt* is, of course, the past participle of the verb *ablehnen*.

I posted an [answer which sparked extended comment discussion](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/25535) between me and another user, arguing that while that view is not wrong, the bolded word can *also* be classified as a predicative adjective (connected to its noun *via* the copula verb) and the sentence therefore as a normal *to be* sentence. Part of my argument was that the word *abgelehnt* can also be used attributively — a position I usually considered open mainly for adjectives:

> Der *abgelehnte* Antrag …

My **questions** being:

- is either of the two classifications (past participle partaking in a stative passive versus adjective) considered wrong?

  - and if that is the case, what are the arguments for not allowing the ‘wrong’ classification?

---

I tried to find similar cases here on Linguistics, but the only one I found was [this question asking about the word found](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/6119). Of course, there is a striking resemblance, but the *found* in the question I just linked was accompanied by further fragments; much more suggesting that *found* be closer to a past participle having replaced a relative clause.

Comment: I would be much obliged if someone can find me a better title.

Comment: I think both classifications are fine. And one 'word' can definitely belong to two different word classes. For example in Polish, 'jutro' can be an adverb as in 'Przyjde jutro' - 'I'm coming tomorrow', and a noun, as in 'Do jutra', lit. 'Till the-next-day' or 'See you tomorrow'. One could also argue that these two are in fact two different words.

Comment: In English, virtually any word can be used as several different parts of speech, due to the  loss of English inflections -- like subjunctive and infinitive markers, which have both been lost in English and conflated with the present, causing no end of difficulty for learners. As to right or wrong -- there are two different ways to analyze the structure, and both are reasonable, and they mean the same thing. Some people will interpret it one way, some the  other; who are we to say who's correct? And why bother in the first place?

Comment: Yeah, @jlawler I was hoping for exactly that answer. In that discussion I asked the other user to tell my *why* my classification should be wrong but never got that one answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tons of research has been written on the problem of distinguishing between verbal passives and adjectival passives, e.g. "The vase was broken."

The following is a summary of Ward, Birner and Huddleston 2002. They mention a number of tests for English - try to see if they work in German.

*It can be considered an adjective if it passes **more than one of any** of the tests below:*

- It can be modified by *very* or *too*;
- "be" can be substituted with another verb (e.g. seem, look, remain);
- The form in question can be prefixed with un-;
- It has a stative interpretation:

*She is injured and will have to miss the next two matches.* [adjectival]

*They were injured when the platform they were standing on collapsed.* [verbal]

They admit there are cases when this construction can be analyzed both as a verbal passive and an adjectival passive, with a slight but significant difference in meaning, e.g. *It was magnetised.*

For more details (ambiguous cases, exceptions etc.), see Ward, Birner and Huddleston 2002, esp. pp. 1438-1440.

My opinion: Since you said "*can **also** be classified*," your position is more balanced and more accurate.

Answer (score 2):

I am inclined to believe that stative passives-verbs without explicit agents are adjectives, as they don't focus on event i.e. they are not eventive. A Verb should show action or event, not mere description and quality of the noun.

*Your application is rejected* shows the state of the application. *The rejected application* is even more clearly an adjective since "rejected" is a part of noun phrase, just like *the found whale*; but not *He found whale*. Although they may be considered ambiguous, I think the absence of agent shows that the focus is not the event or action. [Parameter Hierarchies and Universal Grammar, Ian G. Roberts 2019](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Parameter_Hierarchies_and_Universal_Gram/dcSbDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0)
[image: Parameter Hierarchies and Universal Grammar]

A woman named Kratzer has been quoted on these things, you should search on google books.

[Functional Structure in Nominals, Artemis Alexiadou 2001](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Functional_Structure_in_Nominals/Gm8bZbeWzLgC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=passive%20without%20agent%20are%20adjective&pg=PA200&printsec=frontcover)

[image: Functional Structure in Nominals, By Artemis Alexiadou 2001]

Also, [Perfect Explorations 2012](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Perfect_Explorations/KQwhAAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=kratzer%20stative%20eventive%20passive&pg=PA1&printsec=frontcover), showing in German, adjectival passives are formed with "be", and verbal passives with *wurden* "become"  [image]
and [Non Canonical Passives 2013](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Non_canonical_Passives/oUp7kufhVyIC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=stative%20passive%20%20adjectival%20not%20verbal&pg=PA220&printsec=frontcover)[image: stative/adj vs eventive passive].

Answer (score 1):

It lies in the nature of the participle in German that it combines verbal and adjectival aspects. There is a German name for the participle, *Mittelwort*, which is coined for this double nature.

Having said that, it is conventional to regard the German participle as a form of the verb. The reason is, that it can be regularly derived from the verb and the the verbal lemma behind it is transparent and obvious.

A few participles crossed the border to adjectives diachronically (this happened when the participle survived, but the main verb fell out of use; an example is the German adjective *eigen*).