# Problem Parsing a Sentence

Tags: parsing, verb-phrase

I am having trouble parsing a sentence that I read in Douglas Biber, Susan Conrad, Geoffrey Leech's *Longman Student Grammar of Spoken and Written English* (2002).

The sentence is:

**He was surprised to find himself out of breath**. (p. 50)

To me, the main verb is 'was' and the subject complement is 'surprised'. After that point, I hit a major snag and do not understand how to parse the rest of the sentence.

According to the book authors, the sentence is parsed as:

- **find** - main verb, complex transitive
- **himself** - direct object
- **out of breath** - object predicative/ object complement

I cannot understand how '**find**' is the main verb or what exactly is the complex verb. Is it:
to be surprised to find oneself? What about 'was' in 'was surprised?

Comment: Isn't _was surprised_ the past simple singular **passive** form of the verb _to surprise_?

Comment: Yes, though it could also be just a predicate adjective, especially since there's no agent phrase, and it has an infinitive complement clause.

Comment: you may want to take a look at https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/14376/445

Comment: @AlexB.  The predicative complement of "was" is the AdjP "surprised to find himself out of breath", where the embedded infinitival clause "to find himself out if breath" is complement of "surprised". "Himself" is Od of "find", and the PP "out of breath" is complement of "find"

Comment: @BillJ I simply explained how **Biber et al. 2002** would analyze the sentence, since the OP specifically asked about that book, that’s all. We all know how many competing theories of syntax there are, with their own assumptions, terminology etc.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I am still trying to wrap my head around this sentence and the idea that 'find' is the main verb. My explanation for now is that "was surprised" serves an adjectival function (per Martha Kolln and Loretta Gray's Rhetorical Grammar [2010]). The sentence can be rephrased as: "Surprised, he found himself out of breath." It is easier for me to think of 'Surprised' in the paraphrased sentence as an adjective.

Comment: @BillJ, that would be own approach to parsing the sentence, but yes, I wanted to know how someone could find 'find' as the main verb.

Comment: The book appears to have parsed just the subordinate clause.

Comment: @BillJ, yes, it makes much more sense to me that they have parsed the embedded clause. I am trying to find out where Biber et all. 2002 list the basic sentence structures because I was quite sure that they list 'to be' as as a main verb.

Comment: @Alex B. I still do not understand Biber et al.'s logic for 'find' as the main verb. Thank you for the link on passive voice.

Comment: @Anna77 I don't think I made it clear enough - find is the main verb of what Biber at al. 2002 call OP (object predicative). Please re-read page 50 ("The distinguishing features of the object predicative are ...") and then compare it with section A, Subject Predicatives  (esp. "the main verb has to be a copular verb ...) I decided to delete my first comment.

Comment: (revised) 1. Biber et al. 2002 call out of breath an object predicative (not predicate, as you erroneously said); 2. to find is the main verb in the OP whereas  "was surprised" is a copular verb "be" (the main verb of the SP) followed by a predicative adjective surprised (*was surprised* functioning as the subject predicative) - see e.g. p. 167. I hope it's clearer now.